# How can java class instance be added with string?

Tags: java

```
public class ProductTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Product pr=new Product();
        System.out.println(pr); /// Product@hashcode
    }
}

class Product{
}
```

I can understand the above output of Product@hashcode since `println` method internally uses `valueOf` method and converts it into the string.

But I cannot explain the behavior of output below,

```
public class ProductTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Product pr=new Product();
        String str=pr + "something";
        System.out.println(str); // Product@hashcodesomething
    }
}

class Product{
}
```

How can class instance and string literal be added together?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified in the [Java Language Specification §15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion ([§5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

A string conversion is further specified like this:

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the `toString` method is null, then the string "null"
>   is used instead.

So something like `pr + "something"` is equivalent to `String.valueOf(pr) + "something"`.

Note that I used `valueOf` instead of `toString`, because `pr.toString()` would throw an exception in case `pr` is null. `String.valueOf()` would not.

Comment: I thougt that the string conversion would ONLY make sense when it comes with the primitive types thanks.

Comment: Also, note that String.valueOf(obj) returns the value of obj.toString() if obj is not null and return "null" literal otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple.

```
String str=pr + "something";
```

It is equal to

```
pr.toString() + "something";
```

and pr.toString by default return the Product@hashcode

And that is why we get

```
 System.out.println(str);
```

You can change your toString method of your object and you will see the changes.
--- Going a Little Depeer
All Classes extends by default the toString Method of the Object that is equal to

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So whenever we try to make a contact of a String 
It is happening like mentioned before

```
pr.toString() + "something";
```

If you change your class to override the default method of toString :

```
class Product{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This is my String plus";
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
This is my String plussomething
```

I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `byte` code generated by your it will be clear:

```
       8: new           #19                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      11: dup
      12: invokespecial #21                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      15: aload_1
      16: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: ldc           #26                 // String something
      21: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      24: invokevirtual #31                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      27: astore_2
```

So, from the above byte code, it is clear that Java compiler has compiled to your `String str=pr + "something";` line of code same to the below code.

```
String str = new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pr)
                        .append( "something")
                        .toString();
```

Now if you look at the `StringBuilder#append(Object obj)` ir uses  `String.valueOf(obj)` which further calls `obj.toString()`:

```
@Override
public StringBuilder append(Object obj) {
    return append(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```